# Where can I use keypress in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I want to use keypress so when I type `!` then I need to pass a method. This is the code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete(
        {
            source:"entities#index",
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#search" ).val( ui.item[1] );
                $( "#results").empty();
                $( "#results" ).append( '<a href= '+"entities"+'/'+ui.item[0]+ '>' +ui.item[1]+'</a>' );
                return false;
            }

        }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item[1] + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };


})
```

I want to use keypress in above code I tried this but no success

```
keydown: function(event,ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.Keycode ==35) {
            /// logic here
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try with updater: ?

Comment: Can you please give me the link for example or documentation I am not able to find any revelant source on google

Comment: I figured it out. Cannot find a autocomplete jquery method so I used javascript to get the same result